# A fair 6-sided die is thrown 10 times. What is the probability of rolling a six three times in a row, and the other rolls not being a 6?

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

In 10 rolls, there are 8 positions where the chain of three can start, so there are 8 permutations since dice rolls are interchangeable (their order doesn't matter).

Therefore, I believe that the answer should be $8\times \left(\frac 16\right)^3\times \left(\frac 56\right)^7$. However, I am not $100\%$ sure. Any confirmation is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is right, and your argument for it is solid.  Not sure why it was downvoted...the problem is stated clearly and a detailed attempt at a solution is made.  I have upvoted it accordingly.

Comment: @lulu And I cannot comprehend the 6 upvotes. This kind of questions has been posted probaly hundreds of times on MSE.

Comment: @callculus42  good point.  I expect the upvotes are in response to the initial down vote.

Comment: I accidentally added a bounty what do I do??!

Comment: You put 500 points of your reputation for such an easy question??? :-)

Comment: I wasn't even adding a bounty, I was showing my friend how to add one... That's kinda sad if it cannot be reversed lol

Comment: I am not sure but if it is possible you can answer the question yourself and award it to yourself? Or you can wait for the bounty to expire.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a possibility (the help section says so).

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal probably illegal, but you can have your friend answer, give him the 500, then have him reward one of your answers with a 500 bounty so that you can get your reputation back.

Comment: @mathworker21 I was banned for such operations.

Comment: I was answering the question thinking it was so easy but I won’t now save your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, your logic is sound. It can even be experimentally verified (in Python):

```
import itertools
from fractions import Fraction

def good_roll(roll):
    sixes = [i for i, r in enumerate(roll) if r == 6]
    return len(sixes) == 3 and sixes[0] == sixes[1] - 1 == sixes[2] - 2

num_good_rolls = sum(good_roll(r) for r in itertools.product(range(1, 7), repeat=10))

print(Fraction(num_good_rolls, 6**10))
print(8 * Fraction(1, 6)**3 * Fraction(5, 6)**7)
```

Both statements print 78125/7558272.

Comment: Off-topic, but this answer is such low effort, feel free to not award the bounty.